# Why it is so hard to draw a red rectangle Sprite on white background Layer with cocos2d-x?

Tags: c++, cocos2d-x, cocos2d-x-3.0

Damn it! I want to do the simplest thing in the world via cocos2d-x and and I have problems. I need a white layer on that a red rectangle. First I have found out the in order to color a layer I have to derive from `cocos2d::LayerColor` and `LayerColor::initWithColor(Color4B(255, 255, 255, 255))` then I learnt that in order to draw a rectangle I should override draw method like this:

```
void HelloWorld::draw()
{
DrawPrimitives::setDrawColor4F(1.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f, 1.0f);
DrawPrimitives::drawRect(Point(100,100), Point(400,400));
}
```

This things work separatlely, but they don't work together. I guess when I override draw, then all drawing reduces to these two function calls, hence the background of my layer becomes black. Where is the solution of this simplest thing?

EDIT:

I have tried to call `LayerColor::draw` in the overridden one like this:

```
void HelloWorld::draw()
{
    LayerColor::draw();
DrawPrimitives::setDrawColor4F(1.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f, 1.0f);
DrawPrimitives::drawRect(Point(100,100), Point(400,400));
}
```

Didn't help. Tried to derive from sprite and addChild to the layer like this:

```
class BoardView : public Sprite 
{
public:
    BoardView() : Sprite() 
    {

    }

    virtual void draw() override 
    {
        DrawPrimitives::setDrawColor4F(1.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f, 1.0f);
        DrawPrimitives::drawRect(Point(100,100), Point(400,400));
    }
};
```

But this didn't work either! How can I do this simplest thing? Did I miss something?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the tests for the beta here:
http://www.cocos2d-x.org/reference/native-cpp/V3.0alpha0/d1/d89/namespacecocos2d_1_1_draw_primitives.html#a196155c1b3410485d0b77379acf22e64

I created a simple test class to test it:

```
#ifndef __ccxtest__DrawTest__
#define __ccxtest__DrawTest__

#include <iostream>
#include "cocos2d.h"

class DrawTestLayer : public cocos2d::Layer
{
public:
    CREATE_FUNC(DrawTestLayer);

protected:
    void draw();
};

#endif /* defined(__ccxtest__DrawTest__) */
```

And the implementation:

```
#include "DrawTest.h"

USING_NS_CC;

void DrawTestLayer::draw()
{
glLineWidth(1);
DrawPrimitives::setDrawColor4B(255,255,255,255);
DrawPrimitives::setPointSize(1);

// Anti-Aliased
glEnable(GL_LINE_SMOOTH);

// filled poly
glLineWidth(1);
Point filledVertices[] = { Point(10,120), Point(50,120), Point(50,170), Point(25,200), Point(10,170) };
DrawPrimitives::drawSolidPoly(filledVertices, 5, Color4F(0.5f, 0.5f, 1, 1 ) );
}
```

Finally in the init of the parent scene/layer:

```
auto myLayer = DrawTestLayer::create();
this->addChild(myLayer);
```

And the result is a 5 point polygon.  I tested this on a generic hello world project, and the background image, colors, fonts, etc showed through.

Edit: how to show/hide the drawing:

```
void DrawTestLayer::draw()
{
    if ( drawFlagBoolean ) // controlled by timer or scheduled action
    {
        // draw code here
        // every frame primitives are drawn
    }
}
```

Comment: There are 3 questions: 1) How to draw on a colored layer, which was the original question?  2) How to delete one of the drawn shapes? 3) When you draw do you addChild the line or a rectangle to `this`?

Comment: 1) I believe overriding the draw command in LayerColor will cancel the drawing of primitives.  It's better to add another layer or node because the performance impact is minimal. 2) Use an action sequence or timer to control a bool value that enables the draw code to execute in brackets. When the code isn't executed the shape will disappear. See edit above. 3) no you don't add child.

Comment: Thank you, this completely explains the thing! :)